# ST_Histogram pretty categories

Tags: postgis, raster, postgresql, dem, histogram

I have an elevation raster (DEM) in PostGIS and want to compute a histogram using [ST_Histogram](https://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_Histogram.html). I use this query:

```sql
 SELECT (ST_Histogram( ST_Union(ST_Clip(rast,polygon.geom)),
         1, -- raster band number
         50, -- number of category/bins 
         ARRAY[100] -- width category
        )).* as hist
 FROM elevation.dem,
      (SELECT ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomfromText('Polygon((11 47,11  48 ,12  48 ,12  47 , 11 47))'), 4326 ), 3035) AS geom ) AS polygon
 WHERE ST_Intersects(rast,polygon.geom)
```

Result:

```
 min  | max  | count | percent 
------+------+-------+-------
  478 |  578 |   782 |   5.7
  578 |  678 |  2533 |  18.6
  678 |  778 |  1489 |  10.9
  778 |  878 |   708 |   5.2
  878 |  978 |   635 |   4.7
  978 | 1078 |   635 |   4.7
```

However, I would like to have "pretty" categories like this:

```
 min  | max  | count | percent 
------+------+-------+-------
  400 |  500 |   782 |   5.7
  500 |  600 |  2533 |  18.6
  600 |  700 |  1489 |  10.9
  700 |  800 |   708 |   5.2
  800 |  900 |   635 |   4.7
  900 | 1000 |   635 |   4.7
```

How can I do that?

**SOLUTION**

I found a quite hackerish solution with inspiration from [Andre Silva](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/260896). For my use case it seems to work:

```sql
SELECT min,
       max,
       round((percent*100)::numeric,1) as percent
FROM
(SELECT (ST_Histogram( rast,
         1, -- raster band number
         50, -- number of category/bins
         ARRAY[first_cat, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100] -- width category
        )).* as hist
 FROM
    (
    SELECT rast,
           ceil(((ST_SummaryStats(rast)).min)/100::float)*100 - (ST_SummaryStats(rast)).min AS first_cat
    FROM
        (
        SELECT ST_Union(ST_Clip(rast,polygon.geom)) AS rast
        FROM elevation.dem,
              (SELECT ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomfromText('POLYGON((5.4931640625 45.07662388803723,8.32763671875 45.07662388803723,8.32763671875 42.76637205237248,5.4931640625 42.76637205237248,5.4931640625 45.07662388803723))'), 4326 ), 3035) AS geom ) AS polygon
        WHERE ST_Intersects(rast,polygon.geom)
        ) AS raster
    ) AS raster
) AS hg
```

Result:

```
 min  | max  | percent 
------+------+---------
   -3 |    0 |     0.0
    0 |  100 |     3.4
  100 |  200 |     4.9
  200 |  300 |    10.5
  300 |  400 |     8.2
  400 |  500 |     6.7
  500 |  600 |     5.9
  600 |  700 |     5.0
  700 |  800 |     4.7
  800 |  900 |     4.8
  900 | 1000 |     4.6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [ST_Histogram documentation](https://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_Histogram.html):

> width double precision[]
>
> width: an array indicating the width of each category/bin. If the number of bins is greater than the number of widths, the widths are repeated.

Then, instead of:

```
ARRAY[100]
```

You would need:

```
ARRAY[22,100,100,100,100,100,...] --after '22', repeat '100' 49 times (to add up 50 bins).
```

where 22 is the difference between the min value (478) and the maximum limit in the first bin (500). Then, the next bin will be [500-600) and so on.

Comment: Thanks for you answer so far. I will try it and accept it if it works.